# Probability using percentages of percentages

Tags: probability, percentages

**(A)** 55% of the students at a certain college are females.

**(B)** 7% of the students in this college are majoring in computer science.

**(C)** 4% of the students are women majoring in computer science.

---

If a student is selected at random, find the conditional probability that

(a) the student is female given that the student is majoring in computer science;

(b) this student is majoring in computer science given that the student is a female.

Comment: Hint: think fractions, not percentage. I find it easier to manipulate concepts.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [Bayes rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes'_rule) here:

$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$

So for (a), let $A$ be the event that the student is female and $B$ be the event that the student is a CS major. Therefore, the conditional probability of female given cs major is $\frac{0.04}{0.07}=\frac{4}{7} \approx 57\%$.

For (b), reverse the events, so the conditional probability for cs major given female is $\frac{0.04}{0.55} \approx 7\%$.